# Align a textview to left in a LinearLayout(horizontal)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to make my `Textview` aligned to left have tried. And `android:gravity="left"` but nothing happened.

This is my XML code:

```
  <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
         <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView11"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="10dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:text="Email:"
          android:textSize="20dp"/>
        <EditText
          android:id="@+id/editTextAddress"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="10dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/bg"
          android:hint="Enter Address"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try android:layout_gravity="left"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this use `RelativeLayout` insted of `LinearLayout` and make your `TextView` `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Email:"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:hint="Enter Address"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this use code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Email:"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:hint="Enter Address"/></RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `gravity` attribute is used to set the gravity of the content of the `View`.

The `layout_gravity` attribute is used to set the gravity of the view itself with regards to its parent.

So if you wanted to set the gravity of the text in your `TextView` then you'd use `gravity`. If you want to set the gravity of the `TextView` inside the `LinearLayout` you should use `layout_gravity`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Linear Layout then use :

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Email:"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
```